# Failed to process either the global, per-host or context-specific context.xml file therefore the [/AMWeb] Context cannot be started

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jndi, tomcat9

guys when I am using JNDI in spring boot I have faced the following issues in Tomcat. Please Help me out this following Errors.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to process either the global, per-host or context-specific context.xml file therefore the [/AMWeb] Context cannot be started.
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.FailedContext.startInternal(FailedContext.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 37 more
```

My application.properties

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/users
```

My project Context XML in webapp/META-INF/context.xml for jndi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<context>
    <ResourceLink auth="Container" name="jdbc/users" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</context>
```

My Application Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AgentManagerWeb extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AgentManagerWeb.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AgentManagerWeb.class);
    }
}
```

Can you guess guys about the issues? if you have an idea, give me advice.

Answer (score 3):

You used a lower case c for <context> instead of <Context>.